# parent/child hierarchy & jsonschema

Tags: json, schema, parent-child, hierarchy, jsonschema

I'm trying to come up with a json schema to validate this kind of document:

```
 {
  "rootData": {
    "parent1": [
      {
        "parent1": [
          {
            "leaf1": {
              "attr": "value"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "parent2": [
          {
            "leaf1": {
              "attr": "value"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "leaf1": {
          "attr": "value"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "rootInfo": {
    "i1": 1
  }
 }
```

Some information:

1. "rootData" can contain only one parent, either parent1 or parent2
2. parent1/parent2 can be switched for parent2/parent1 at any position in the hierarchy
3. there is no depth limit: as long as a parent contains another parent, we can go deeper and deeper.

I think I was able to figure out how to represent the hierarchical nature of the embedded parent/child part.
But I don't know how to define the "rootData" top level, more precisely the choice between "parent1" or "parent2" since I can not use oneOf (I think...)

```
    {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "parent1": {
      "$id": "#parent1",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "parent1": {
          "$ref": "#node"
        }
      }
    },
    "parent2": {
      "$id": "#parent2",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "parent2": {
          "$ref": "#node"
        }
      }
    },
    "leaf1": {
      "$id": "#leaf1",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "leaf1": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "attr": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "attr"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "node": {
      "$id": "#node",
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "oneOf": [
          {
            "$ref": "#parent1"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#parent2"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#leaf1"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "rootData": {
      "properties": {
        //I tried several things here minProperties/maxProperties or oneOf ... but I actually don't know how to reuse my previous parent1 or parent2 definitions ...
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is welcome!

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Add `"required":["parent1"]` and `"required":["parent2"]` constraints to your parent1 and parent2 definitions, and use `oneOf`:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
    "definitions": {
        "parent1": {
            "$id": "#parent1",
            "type": "object",
            "required": ["parent1"],
            "properties": {
                "parent1": {"$ref": "#node"}
            }
        },
        // ...
    },
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "rootData": {
            "oneOf": [
                {"$ref": "#parent1"},
                {"$ref": "#parent2"}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

If you tried using `anyOf` and that worked, that's because your `parent1` and `parent2` definitions validate against each other: `parent1` validates against a `parent2` object, since it ignores the "parent2" property, and is valid without a "parent1" property; and vice-versa for "parent1".

Comment: thanks for the help! But it's still failing with the updated mapping. https://jsonschemalint.com/ returns "refVal1 is not defined"

Comment: @user12824955 I'm not sure what that error means, but it sounds like a different problem. What happens when you actually try it in your program?